# Pyrite oxidation

Tags: geochemistry, minerals, homework, groundwater

How much pyrite has to be oxidized to produce a sulfate concentration of 15 mM?

If the solution initially has a pH of 8, roughly what would the pH drop to if there is no buffering of acidity?

Comment: Do you know what is the oxidation reaction of pyrite?

Comment: FeS2(s) +  15/4 O2(aq) +  7/2 H2O → Fe(OH)3(s) + 4H+(aq) + 2SO42-(aq) so I guess 7.5 mmol of pyrite is needed to produce 15 mmol of sulfate

Comment: Good. Now, if for each mol of pyrite you're generating 4 protons, what would be the effect on pH? Also notice that the question has mM - this implies a volume. If there is no other information, I reckon assuming 1 litre is safe.

Comment: Please see the guide on how to ask homework questions: https://earthscience.meta.stackexchange.com/a/317/39